# How to correctly format the output with Awk printf command?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I have the following file:

```
echo filename
    dfT08r352|30.5|2010/06/01|2016/08/29|2281|6.24503764544832|74.9404517453799|
    zm00dr121|37|2008/03/05|2011/09/12|1285.95833333333|3.52076203513575|42.249144421629|
    ccvd00121|41.6|2008/03/05|2012/03/05|1461|4|48|
    sddf00121|39.6|2008/03/05|2012/09/10|1649.95833333333|4.51733972165184|54.208076659822|
    fttt00121|41|2008/03/05|2013/09/16|2020.95833333333|5.53308236367785|66.3969883641342|
    ghhyy0121|42.2|2008/03/05|2014/03/18|2203.95833333333|6.03410905772302|72.4093086926762|
```

I am trying to format this file using awk printf to have the following desired format:

1. keep the same order of fields (left-->right)
2. have comma ", " FS
3. only for the l**ast three fields ($5, $6, $7)** having all the
   numbers to be 4 digits, if less have a leading zero and only 2
   digits after the point like 0123.12 or 1234.10

I wrote the following awk command

```
awk -F"|" '{print $1","$2","$3","$4}{format = "%04.2f,%04.2f,%04.2f,"}{printf format, $5,$6,$7}' filename
```

however the below output has the following issues:

1. is not in order (left-->right)
2. do not have the leading zero

   ```
   dfT08r352,30.5,2010/06/01,2016/08/29
   2281.00,6.25,74.94,zm00dr121,37,2008/03/05,2011/09/12
   1285.96,3.52,42.25,ccvd00121,41.6,2008/03/05,2012/03/05
   1461.00,4.00,48.00,sddf00121,39.6,2008/03/05,2012/09/10
   1649.96,4.52,54.21,fttt00121,41,2008/03/05,2013/09/16
   2020.96,5.53,66.40,ghhyy0121,42.2,2008/03/05,2014/03/18
   ```

Can someone please let me know what is my mistake and how to fix it?

Comment: FYI, for comma separation without quoting each comma you could use `'BEGIN {OFS=","}'` or just `-v OFS=,`—but that doesn't answer your broader question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the fields in the right order, but your first print statement adds a newline (Output Record Separator), so your data's there, but just wrapped unexpectedly.

The second issue is that you're telling printf to use a width of 4; that includes the decimal point and the two digits after it, leaving only one for the leading digit and none for any padding. Try using 5 as the width, so that your data is padded up to four total numbers. If you want 4 digits *before* the decimal point, then change the width to 7 instead.

This is the shortest change I made from your program to something that outputs what I think you want:

```
awk -F"|" '{
  format = "%05.2f,%05.2f,%05.2f"; 
  print $1","$2","$3","$4"," sprintf(format, $5,$6,$7)}' filename
```

I combined multiple `{ }` blocks into one, and also combined the print statements into one.

If I was to write your awk statement from scratch, I might do something like this:

```
awk -v FS=\| -v OFS=, '{
  $5=sprintf("%05.2f", $5); 
  $6=sprintf("%05.2f", $6); 
  $7=sprintf("%05.2f", $7); 
  print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' filename
```

It explicitly sets the input Field Separator, the Output Field Separator, explicitly converts each of the fields on its own, then prints the desired fields, with the OFS separating them.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it:

```
awk -F \| -v OFS=, '{ NF--; for(i = NF-2; i <= NF; i++) $i = sprintf("%07.2f", $i) } 1' filename
```

Comment: @ Sato Katsura, Tnx a lot it works perfectly. May I ask you please explain to ur scripts to understand it! I am new in Awk. Only need the explanation for this part of ur script : { NF--; for(i = NF-2; i <= NF; i++) $i = sprintf("%07.2f", $i) } 1'